# RavenDB BulkInsert() fails with 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb, ravenhq

I've recently migrated my environment and now a process that uses BulkInsert is not working. It is resulting in a 403 Forbidden response from the db server.

The previous environment had the database running as a Windows service on the same server as my application and access was set up differently.  Now I'm using RavenHQ on a remote host, using an API Key.  I'm sure the privileges have changed so I'm wondering if that's why BulkInsert is resulting in 403 error.

I've searched but I cannot find anything that explicitly states what privileges are required for the various raven operations.  My understanding from [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/ravendb/403/ravendb/SUneV3yEu_c/4UuG0_9plKAJ) is that there are at least *some* that require higher privileges.  Can anybody point me to documentation on specifics?  Or otherwise shine some light on the subject? Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm the 403 is coming from the BulkInsert operation? Or just something that uses BulkInsert?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I think it's because the example connection string RavenHQ gives you containing your API key does not actually include your database name.

Try adding ";Database=[myDb]" to the end of your connection string URL or passing your database name explicitly as the first parameter to bulkInsert()